# Excel VBA code modification so only alert me once for same item

Tags: excel, vba

I manage a contract log that list out all of my company's contracts with the effective and expiring date.

I've written VBA code that alerts me whenever any one of the contracts is about to expire; a message box will show up that tells me the "carrier's contract# is about to expire". (Please see the code below).

However, because there are different Amendments for each contract, the same contract number may be listed out multiple times in the spreadsheet. If one contract is about to expire, the code notifies me multiple times.

How can I modify my code so it only alerts me once for the same contract number?

Column A is the carrier name, column B is the contract #, Column C is the Amendment# and Column G is the expiration date for each contract.

Let me know if I didn't make myself clear enough or more information is needed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim rngC As Range
With Worksheets("NON-TPEB SC LOGS(OPEN)")
    For Each rngC In .Range(.Range("G5"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
        If rngC.Value > Now And (rngC.Value - Now) < 7 Then
            MsgBox .Cells(rngC.Row, 1).Value & "'s " & _
                   .Cells(rngC.Row, 2).Value & " is expiring!!"
        End If
    Next rngC
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to keep track of contract numbers that have already been checked.  This is how you might implement it.

After you do your logic test (`If rngC.Value > Now And...)` check to see if the `contractNum` exists in the dictionary. That's what this line does:

`If Not checkedDict.Exists(contractNum) Then`

- If that evaluates `True`, then the contract has not already been checked, so we add it to the dictionary, and display the message box.
- If that evaluates to `False`, then the contract does exist in the
  dictionary, so can do nothing, since the user has already been
  informed of the expiring contract.

Here is the full code (untested):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Requires reference to Microsoft SCripting Runtime
' or, simply declare the scripting obects as generic "Object" variables.

Dim checkedDict As Scripting.Dictionary
'Dim checkedDict as Object  '## Use this line (andcomment out the preceding line if you cannot enable the library reference to Scripting Runtime

Dim contractNum As String
Dim carrierName As String
Dim rngC As Range

Set checkedDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("NON-TPEB SC LOGS(OPEN)")
        For Each rngC In .Range(.Range("G5"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
            carrierName = .Cells(rngC.Row, 1).Value
            contractNum = .Cells(rngC.Row, 2).Value

            If rngC.Value > Now And (rngC.Value - Now) < 7 Then
                If Not checkedDict.Exists(contractNum) Then
                    checkedDict.Add contractNum, carrierName
                    MsgBox carrierName & "'s " & _
                       contractNum & " is expiring!!"
                Else:
                    ' this contract# already exists, so, do nothing
                    ' because the user was already informed.
                End If
            End If

        Next rngC
    End With

    set checkedDict = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above code requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library, or, simply `Dim checkedDict as Object` instead.

Comment: How do I make reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library. I tried set checkedDict as Object, Run Time error occurred

Comment: From within the VBE, Tools | References and then scroll down until you find "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" ([screenshot](http://imgur.com/WZZQtWM)).  If there's still an error, then let me know what line causes the error and what the error msg says.

Comment: In order to work without the reference to the Scripting Runtime, you need to declare with `Dim checkedDict As Object` and to assign with `Set checkedDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. Otherwise Excel doesn't know that you want to use a Dictionary.

Comment: still error, the error message says Run-time erroe "91" : Object variable with block variable not set with "If Not checkedDict.Exists(contractNum) Then" highlighted.

Comment: @user2483063 I think that is because of what Stenci noticed. We have not created the dictionary object, that would explain the error.  Revised code should fix that. Sorry!

Comment: @user2483063 my previous comment was (partially) wrong, because I didn't pay attention to the code. You need to create the Dictionary object, and there are two ways: (1) `Dim checkedDict As New Scripting.Dictionary`, and (2) either `Dim checkedDict As Scripting.Dictionary` or `Dim checkedDict As Object` followed by `Set checkedDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. If you have the reference both the systems work, otherwise only the latter. The former is best because Excel knows what object you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

I always use an `AlreadyChecked` string variable to keep track of what has already been processed.

In the loop add a check like this:

```
Dim AlreadyChecked As String

AlreadyChecked = "@"
If Instr(AlreadyChecked, "@" & ValueToCheck & "@") = 0 Then
  AlreadyChecked = AlreadyChecked & ValueToCheck & "@"
  ... do your stuff ...
End If
```

Comment: I probably would use a Dictionary, but this is a neat approach to the problem. Not sure it is 100% false-positive-proof (e.g., would containing your delimited possibly raise a partial match?), but I think it would work the vast majority of the time. +1

Comment: It's a good way when you are sure the delimiter character doesn't appear in the data. The only problem I ever had with it is that it gets slow when the string is concatenated thousands of times. How would you use a Dictionary in VBA?

Comment: see my answer below, since you asked :)  It should always be faster than storing/comparing a long string, too.

Comment: Thanks. Nice trick to use Dictionary in VBA, I have been missing them! I will stick with my system for quick and dirty cases and remember about Scripting.Dictionary for more serious cases.